# not all code paths return a value. In C#

Tags: c#

So it's a school assignment (I'm a beginner, started with c# this week).
We have a class that stores the functions.
This function is supposed to check if a person can go on the carousel or not.
variables:
bool hasHeartCondition
int age
int cm

```
public bool CanJoyride(int age, int cm, bool hasHeartCondition)
    {
        if (hasHeartCondition == true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (hasHeartCondition == false)
        {
            if (age >= 18)
            {
                if (cm >= 130 && cm <= 210)
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            else if (age >= 12)
            {
                if (cm >= 150 && cm <= 210)
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The reason I'm making a new question for this is cause I can't really follow the code in the questions like this. Cause I'm really new to this.

Comment: Replace the last `else` with just `return false`

Comment: Hint: when you post a question here, do not say it's a school assignment

Comment: If the `age >= 18` and the height doesn't fall in that range? And also - if the `age >= 12` but height isn't in range?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Trace through the code. Is there a path that causes you to get to the end without hitting a `return` statement? That's why you're seeing this error. Take the appropriate action and make sure you `return` "something".

Comment: @meJustAndrew -- There's nothing wrong with asking questions about school assignments, as long as you follow the rules: show effort, show research, ask specific, on-topic question,

Comment: @rory.ap you are right, but do you see... it's still just an advise, and people make the first impression that the queation is low quality just because it is a school assignment, as most of these questions are. Indeed sometimes they can show research effort, but most of the time, the questions asked to solve a school assignment are not well researched, are unclear or duplicate. Sorry for my opinion, but this is how I find it. Pretty much because school assignments are not surprising corner cases or any programming unreached topic, they are just different exercises

Comment: @meJustAndrew -- A well-written, thoroughly-researched question brimming with code samples will stand on its own.  I don't care if you shout in the first line in bold text that it's a school assignment.  Poor quality vs. good quality is not affected by the proclamation that it's a school assignment.

Comment: @meJustAndrew This question isn't a low quality question because it's a school assignment.  It's a low quality question because it's poorly researched, doesn't explain what about his problem he does/doesn't understand, etc.  It has nothing to do with it being a school assignment.  It being a school assignment is *irrelevant*, and it'd be better to omit it just because it's a waste of time to read, but that's not what makes the question bad.

Comment: @rory.ap I just gave an *advise* in not to mention it is a school assignment because on most of the readers this has a psychological impact based on their experience. I didn't said and I will **never** say that this is making it a bad question.

Comment: @Servy I would address the comment above to you too, and with all the respect. I just don't want to be misunderstood.

Comment: @meJustAndrew I also reject your assertion that a good question that's indicated is for school will be improperly marked as being a low quality question.  When people indicate that they're writing something for an assignment, but it's a great question, it tends to be received well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't return any value at the end of your method. You can re write your method like this. It is more understandable and should fill your reqirments.

```
public bool CanJoyride(int age, int cm, bool hasHeartCondition)
{
    if (hasHeartCondition)        
        return false;


    if(age >= 18 && cm >= 130 && cm <= 210)
        return true;


     if (age >= 12 && cm >= 150 && cm <= 210)
        return true;

     return false;         
}
```

You should avoid writing code in arrow way. That means avoid nested if, because the code become unreadable and hard to follow.